# Can Zend be used with PHP ADOdb?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, adodb, foxpro

I have to select a framework (or role my own) and one of the databases I have to connect to is FoxPro.  I found a driver here at http://adodb.sourceforge.net/ and I am guessing it's okay to use, but I don't know if I can use it in Zend.  I thought Zend came with an ORM too so I didn't now if I could use it with that.  Thanks.

EDIT:  A better question may be can zend_db be used with adodb?  can I use both of these at the same time in my zend implementation?  zend_db and pdo do no have a foxpro adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend *does* include [Zend_Db_Adapter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html) which provides a loose abstraction around basic database operations.

It also provides [Zend_Db_Table](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html) (and other associated classes) which implement the [Table Data Gateway](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) pattern.

But you *don't* have to use any of Zend's database functionality if you don't want to.  So the answer to your question is definitely yes.  You can use ADODb in a Zend application -- or any other approach to database access that you may prefer.  Just build your model objects using your db abstraction of choice, and then use them like normal from within your Zend action controllers.